# Function to calculate dynamic moving average using rolling() in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate a dynamic moving average based on values in existing column. The operation i am trying to achieve is that,
I have a sample dataframe with three columns a,b,c. I want to write a dynamic function to apply to my entire dataframe where a new column d is created such that

Column d values should be calculated as moving averages of values in column c based on the window size in column b . If value in column b is negative , average has to be calculated backwards, if it is 0 , average will be nan , if the value of column b is greater than or less than the length of the data frame, then average will be equal to value in column C.

To understand better ;
df['d'] at index 0 should be the  average of [100, 53, 48, 28] because df['b'] at index 0 is 4. Similary df['d'] at index 1 should be average of [53,100] because df['b'] at index 1 is -2. Because it is -2 it goes in reverse order. Likewise for df['d] at index2 should be average of [48,28]because df['b'] at index 2 is 2. df['d'] at index 3 should be = 'nan' as df['b']at index3 is 0. df['d'] at index 4 should be = 1 as df['b']at index 4 is 1. Finally the df['d'] at index 5 should be equal to 202 because df['b']at index 5 is 4 .There are no 4 rows ahead to calculate the moving average.

My code is as below and it is giving me weird results. Any help is appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
data = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'b': [4, -2, 2, 0, 1, 4],
    'c': [100, 53, 48, 28, 18, 202]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to calculate the custom rolling average
def custom_rolling_average(window_values):
    if len(window_values) > 0:
        return window_values.mean()
    else:
        return np.nan

# Calculate the rolling average
df['d'] = np.nan
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    window_size = abs(row['b'])
    window_start = max(i - window_size + 1, 0)
    window_end = i
    window_values = df.loc[window_start:window_end, 'c'].astype(float)
    if window_size == 0:
        df.at[i, 'd'] = np.nan
    else:
        df.at[i, 'd'] = custom_rolling_average(window_values)
```

Comment: There are multiple problems: (1) Due to the `abs` you ignore the sign of the window. Better write separate code for positive and negative window. (2) `i - window_size` doesnt make sense if the window size is positive. The beginning shouldn't be before the current position. (3) Be aware that the end of a slice in `df.loc[...]` is inclusive, not exclusive as in regular Python data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    start = df.index.get_loc(row.Index)
    end = start + row.b
    end = end if (end > 0) & (end <= len(df)) else None
    step = 1 if row.b > 0 else -1
    df.loc[row.Index, 'd'] = df.iloc[start:end:step]['c'].mean()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   a  b    c       d
0  1  4  100   57.25
1  2 -2   53   76.50
2  3  2   48   38.00
3  4  0   28     NaN
4  5  1   18   18.00
5  6  4  202  202.00
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien. I have a follow up to the above . My actual data frame is of the dimensions 20178 rows x 10 columns. I am unable to run the function on it and it crashes. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data, please?